# Write a single congruence?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

> Write a single congruence that is equivalent to the pair of congruences:
>
> $x\equiv 1(\mod4)$ and $x\equiv 2 (\mod 3)$.

I am new to Number Theory/ Modular Arithmetic. Just started reading the theory from a book yesterday. Earlier I had read about it a little on the internet. I know the basic definitions and some properties. I do not understand the question properly. What does writing a single congruence mean? Does it mean I have to find $x$? How do I solve this question. Do I need to use any theorem like the Chinese Remainder Theorem or something else? I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem, look at the possible residues modulo $12$

Comment: Yes, it is an application of the *Chinese Remainder theorem* and of *Bézout's identity*.

Comment: @Bernard, Although I have read a little about the Chinese Remainder Theorem on the Internet before, this problem appears in my book before the Chinese Remainder Theorem is introduced.

Comment: You don't need the theorem to work out a special case.   For instance, the pair of congruences $x\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $x\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ would be equivalent to $x\equiv 0 \pmod {12}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Start from a Bézout's relation between the moduli, say $\; 4-3=1$, and consider the analog of the linear interpolation polynomial: for any $a, b \in\mathbf Z$,
$$a\cdot 4-b\cdot3\equiv \begin{cases}a \mod 3, \\[1ex]  b\mkern 1.5mu \mod 4. \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

you can literally turn this into $3z+2=4y+1;3z+1=4y$; take this mod 3 and get 1=y; so plug $y=3a+1$ and get back $3z+1=12a+4$ and then add 1 to both sides restoring the original getting $3z+2=12a+5$  so you get $x\equiv 5 \bmod 12$.  This is basically CRT done via linear polynomials.